# How to detect what scrollviewer (parent or child) start scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, scrollview

In my app I have one main ScrollViewer and many DataGrids with embedded scrollviewers in them. Thanks to this article https://serialseb.com/blog/2007/09/03/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from/ and comments below I made parent and children scrollviwers work fine for me. Every time I start scrolling with mouse my parent scroll starts work when it reaches to any DataGrid then DataGrid's scrollviewer does it work and when whole content is scrolled it returns scrolling to the parent (main ScrollViewer). But that logic is not enough for me. I need this: if I start scrolling DataGrid (using child scrollviewer) it will scroll ONLY this DataGrid (when child ScrollViwer can't scroll any more it doesn't return scrolling to parent), but only if there is something to scroll on it. If not, the main window will scroll again. And if I start scrolling the main content than any of child ScrolViewers shouldn't react.

My questions is: how can I detect what UIElement start scrolling it's content and continue to scroll only it's content?

Simply put I want the same scroll parent/child logic as we have here on stackoverflow (try to scroll elements with code and whole page).

I think the similar idea is in this question [WPF detect scrolling parent Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309883/wpf-detect-scrolling-parent-control) but it's not suitable for me because I have DataGrid instead of Popup.

I think about IsFocusable property but honestly I don't know where in my code I can check it.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class ScrollViewerCorrector
    {
        public static void SetApplyScrolling(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ApplyScrollingProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ApplyScrollingProperty =

            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ApplyScrolling", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollViewerCorrector),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnApplyScrollingPropertyChanged));

        public static void OnApplyScrollingPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var viewer = sender as ScrollViewer;

            if (viewer == null) return;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue) viewer.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPreviewMouseWheel;

            else viewer.PreviewMouseWheel -= OnPreviewMouseWheel;

        }

        private static List<MouseWheelEventArgs> _wheelEventArgsList = new List<MouseWheelEventArgs>();

        private static void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollControl = sender as ScrollViewer;

            if (!e.Handled && sender != null && !_wheelEventArgsList.Select(args => (args.Source)).Contains(sender))
            {
                var previewEventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
                {
                    RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseWheelEvent, Source = sender
                };

                var originalSource = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

                _wheelEventArgsList.Add(previewEventArg);

                originalSource.RaiseEvent(previewEventArg);

                _wheelEventArgsList.Remove(previewEventArg);


                //check if any of children handled the event
                if (!previewEventArg.Handled && ((e.Delta > 0 && scrollControl.VerticalOffset == 0) ||
                                                 (e.Delta <= 0 && scrollControl.VerticalOffset >=
                                                     scrollControl.ExtentHeight - scrollControl.ViewportHeight)))

                {
                    e.Handled = true;

                    var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);

                    eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;

                    eventArg.Source = sender;

                    var parent = (UIElement)((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent;

                    parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);

                }

            }

        }
```

**MainView.xaml**

```
<rui:ReactiveUserControl x:TypeArguments="viewModels:MainViewModel"
                         x:Class="AnalyticalReporting.UI.Views.MainView"
                         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AnalyticalReporting.UI.ViewModels"
                         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                         xmlns:rui="http://reactiveui.net"
                         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MNS.Common.UI.Controls;assembly=MNS.Common.UI"
                         mc:Ignorable="d"
                         d:DesignHeight="1024" d:DesignWidth="1280"
                         Background="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="controls:ScrollViewerCorrector.ApplyScrolling" Value="True" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <rui:ViewModelViewHost x:Name="DisplayingViewModelViewHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ViewModel="{Binding .}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="InfoCardList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</rui:ReactiveUserControl>
```